# Java Hibernate sqlGroupProjection mysql Syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, criteria

i need to translate this `SQL expression`into `Hibernate` using `Criteria`

```
select id,field1,field2,count(*) from my_table 
group by field1,field2 having count(*)>1;
```

here is my code so far.

```
    final Session session = ......
    ProjectionList projectionList = (ProjectionList)emptyProjection();
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"),"id"); 
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("codeI"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("codeII"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("count(*)","having count(*)>1",new String[]{},new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER}));     
    final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class).setProjection(projectionList).setResultTransformer(transformer(MyClass.class));
    return new ArrayList<MyClass>(criteria.list());
```

my problem is

the criteria is generating this SQL.

```
group by
    this_.FIELD1,
    this_.FIELD2,

having
    count(*)>1
```

as you can see the second group by is followed by a `COMMA` `this_.FIELD2,` and mySQL is throwing `SyntaxError`

**UPDATE**

here is my hibernate.cfg

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> 
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
```

and we are using `mysql 5.5.29` and `HIBERNATE 4.2.3`

i hope somebody give a tip.

best regards..

Comment: Shot in the dark - what SQL dialect is set in your config file?

Comment: and probably hibernate version you use is needed

Comment: Hibernate Version 4.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate does not support a **having** clause in the Criteria API.  Your code is tantalizing close to the SQL you want, but what you've actually specified is just another **group by** condition, hence the comma.  Here is a feature request from forever ago: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1043.

If you must use a criteria, then you can use a subquery which will end up being slow.  HQL does support the clause so you could do it that way.

More discussion and examples: [Hibernate Criteria API - HAVING clause work arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467172/hibernate-criteria-api-having-clause-work-arounds).

Comment: oh i see. can you please post some subquery code or something related or a link thanks a lot..